# What is this Marvel gauntlet that someone's grandmother knitted?

Tags: marvel, object-identification

I got forwarded this piece of online humour:

It depicts a knitted yellow gauntlet, with what looks like 4 colored "jewels" on the knuckles and a clear "jewel" in the middle of the wrist, with a caption "When your grandma finds out you're a marvel fan".

I assume that this joke was based on some real piece of Marvel equipment, but not familiar enough with the universe to know what it was (from afar, I thought it was meant to be Wolverine's hand with claw sockets, but it clearly doesn't seem to be it).

## Please help identify what this Marvel gauntlet the knitted item is.

[image: The yellow knitted gauntlet with coloured jewels along the knuckles and on the back of the hand with the caption as mentioned above]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the Infinity Gauntlet, a glove for holding the Infinity Stones. We see this across various universes in Marvel. For example, in *The Infinity Gauntlet* comic series run we have the Infinity Gauntlet with the Infinity Gems.

[image: The Inifnity Gauntlet front cover with Thanos wielding the full Infinity Gauntlet and Mistress Death over his shoulder and various other characters in the background]

However, this is most likely a reference to the Infinity Gauntlet from the Marvel Cinematic Universe to hold the Infinity Stones.

[image: Thanos in Wakanda places the final Infinity Stone, the Mind Stone, into the Infinity Gauntlet to complete it, the power surges through him]

Answer (score 2):

It's Thanos' Infinity Gauntlet. The gems are the concentrated remnants of a collapsed universe that existed before ours. They were forged by beings unknown.

Thanos was even able to defeat Galactus with it.

It can only be wielded by beings of significant power.